# `sudo tar` but own the resulting file

Tags: permissions, sudo, tar

I want to put a bunch of files into an archive with `tar`. However, I don't have permission to access all of them, so I have to do `sudo tar`.

However, now that `root` has run the `tar`, the resulting archive is also owned by root, and I must change permissions on the `.tar.gz`, which is a bit tedious.

Isn't there a "partial `sudo`" of some sort to tell `tar` to *access* the files as root, but create the file as me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of a fact that often annoys or surprises people, that redirection occurs in the shell and is unaffected by sudo.

Use `-` (aka `/dev/stdout`) as the filename and then redirect the output to a filename of your choice. It will be owned by you, created with your default permissions (as defined by `umask`).

```
sudo tar czf - [more options and file/dir names] > myfile.tar.gz
```

The redirection happens as your UID, while the `tar` itself runs as root.